# using a map to apply some function into array

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0, typescript1.8

I am so new on typescript/javascript that I would like to modify each element of array with some function like following code. but I am wondering if there is a more concise/clear way to build my expected array from variable?

```
const variable  =  [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
function add(a: number, b: number): number {
  return a + b;
}
console.log(variable.map((i: number) => {return add(100, i)})) # =>[ 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106 ]
```

Comment: You can skip the `return` statement in map's callback and remove curly brackets if only single expression is needed.

Comment: You have tagged your question with [tag:typescript2.0], which is for questions that apply *only* to TypeScript 2.0 and no other version of TypeScript, so for example *not* to TypeScript 1.8. You have also tagged your question with [tag:typescript1.8], which is for questions that apply *only* to TypeScript 1.8 and no other version of TypeScript, so for example *not* to TypeScript 2.0. Which of the two versions *are* you using? And why do you believe that your question only applies to that *specific* version? Are you aware that the versions you are using have been obsolete for over 3 years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES6, if you have single expression as a return statement then you can simply re-write it as:

```
variable.map((i: number) => add(100, i))
```

Also, if you declare `variable` as an array of `number` like:

```
const variable: number[]  =  [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Then inside `.map()` method you will not need to declare `i: number` as that would be automatically inferred. So, the `.map()` logic will become even more concise like:

```
variable.map(i => add(100, i))
```

Or, you can simply do it without using the `add()` function here:

```
variable.map(i => 100 + i)
```

Answer (score 2):

One semi-generic approach would be to define a function `add()`, which itself returns a function where the current `item` being mapped is added to the fixed `amount` specified (ie `100`):

```js
const add = (amount) => (item) => item + amount;

console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6].map(add(100)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to create an add function, you can directly add the number to current value during mapping.

```js
const variable  =  [1,2,3,4,5,6] 

console.log(variable.map(num => num + 100))
```